# How to read in three integers based in one line by cstdio::scanf?

Tags: c++, c, scanf

I have data for which using cin/in is too slow.
There are three integers per line :

```
1 2 2
3 4 1
5 6 122
6 4 7
```

How to read-in each line in loop, to achive result (for first iteration) :

```
x==1;
y==2;
z==2;
etc.
```

?

How to to do it using cstdio::scanf ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
 while(scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c) != EOF) {
   ... do stuff ...
 }
```

Comment: thanks, but one thing is strange, - insted of while, Ive for(), and in "do staff" I have cout and printing output get place only when whole for loop is ended - not in each iteration, isn't it strange behaviour ?

Comment: The spaces in the format string are unnecessary and just serve to slow things down by an unmeasurable amount.